# SQLite Join in Windows 8 Metro C# with sqlite-net

Tags: c#, sql, join, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I am using C# and SQLite for a Database for a Windows-8-Metro-App. I want to use a Join-Command, but don't know how to read the given back data. This will not work:

```
db.Query<Person>("SELECT * FROM Person, Job WHERE Person.JobID = Job.ID");
```

And this is not implemented:

```
db.Query<Person, Job>("SELECT * FROM Person, Job WHERE Person.JobID = Job.ID");
```

Someone has an idea how to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The join is fine, if antiquated - you should use the newer syntax

```
 SELECT * FROM Person INNER JOIN Job ON Person.JobID = Job.ID
```

Your problem is in what you are returning - you are returning both Person data and Job data - so you need to create a class that matches the data structure that you are returning - or return just a person, or a job.

```
 db.Query<Person>("SELECT Person.* FROM Person INNER JOIN Job ON Person.JobID = Job.ID");           
 db.Query<Job>("SELECT Job.* FROM Person INNER JOIN Job ON Person.JobID = Job.ID");
```

Comment: how  to  provide  both  table  results  as  an  ITEM to  listbox  ..??? @podiluska

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use it properly, you can try.

```
 var db = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(_dbPath);
 var query = from person in await db.Table<Person>().ToListAsync()
                    join job in await db.Table<Job>().ToListAsync()
                    on person.JobID = job.ID
                    select new
                    {
                        Name=person.Name
                    };
```

Comment: Doesn't this first select all data into the memory? It doesn't do join on SQL side?

Comment: This suggestion should be deleted