# How to set property class while sqlite join returning data from multiple tables in windows store c#/xaml app

Tags: c#, sqlite, properties, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12234687/sqlite-join-in-windows-8-metro-c-sharp-with-sqlite-net) answer. It tells to *create a class that matches the data structure that you are returning*. So I made a class like this

```
public class PersonJob
{
    public Person person { get; set; }

    public Job job { get; set; }
}

var data = db.Query<PersonJob>("SELECT * FROM Person, Job WHERE Person.JobID = Job.ID");
```

So the result data has results but the property `person` and `job` is null. My textblocks are bound with the properties of `Person` and `Job` class. Please give me appropriate suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query returns several columns in a single table.
If the `Person` table has columns `ID`, `Name`, and `JobID`, and the `Jobs` table has columns `ID`, and `Description`, the result would look like this:

```
ID Name     JobID ID Description
-- -------- ----- -- -------------
 1 John Doe    10 10 Bottle Washer
 2 Jane Roe    10 10 Bottle Washer
 3 Xyroid      11 11 CEO
```

So you would need to create a single class with these five fields.

To avoid duplicate fields or field names, and to make it work even if the tables are extended later, you should list the fields you needs in the `SELECT` statement:

```sql
SELECT Person.ID AS PersonID, Person.Name, Job.ID AS JobID, Job.Description
FROM Person INNER JOIN Job ON Person.JobID = Job.ID
```

This would require a class like this:

```
class PersonWithJob
{
    public int PersonID ...
    public string Name ...
    public int JobID ...
    public string Description ...
}
```

Comment: So, in short I have to create another class which will have properties defined explicitly and I should not use * in SQL query instead that I should use required properties only. Can't we use inheritances ?

Comment: Inheritance might help, or not. What matters is that the fields of your class match the fields returned by the `SELECT`.